# How can i get accurate time with 1 microsecond resolution in python?

Tags: python, time

How can I get clock time with 1 microsecond accuracy in Python?

The problem is `time.time()` has about 15 microseconds of resolution.

Comment: Maybe you're looking for https://docs.python.org/3/library/time.html#time.perf_counter

Comment: What OS are you using?

Comment: I am using win 10.

Answer (score 1):

This is heavily dependent on the OS that you are using, if you are on Linux or MacOS then [time.time()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/time.html#time.time) will have an accuracy of ~1 μs. The reason that `time.time()` on Windows has a ~15 ms inaccuracy, is because it can't provide a more accurate time.

Note: If you want to time your code you should NOT use `time.time()`, instead use [time.perf_counter()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/time.html#time.perf_counter) or [time.process_time()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/time.html#time.process_time) which uses the CPU time and is much more accurate.

Comment: Nice answer.  Another option for timing code execution, specific to Python, is the `timeit` module or `%timeit` magic in IPython.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But 1 quastion , on Linux or MacOS  time.time() will have an accuracy of ~1 milisecond or 1 microsecond?

Comment: @Kumar That should've been μs instead of ms - updated

Answer (score 0):

Try with the `datetime` library:

```
import datetime
print(datetime.datetime.now())
```

**Output:**

```
2022-06-20 07:12:19.208703
```